# How to show follow Twitter account after someone shares the article

Tags: twitter

I have implemented Twitter card with mentioning my username @username, hashtag and all other information.

I want to know how can I show my Twitter profile follow button after someone shares my article or page.

Take a look at the screenshot below where I have share someone's post via their website.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The "who to follow" dialogue after tweeting is a Twitter feature—the list is generated automatically. Twitter has [a support article](https://support.twitter.com/articles/227220-about-twitter-s-suggestions-for-who-to-follow#) with some details about how it decides who appears there.

Comment: I  did little experiment on it.
I have tweeted the article from website where I never came across and while tweeting I have mentioned twitter handle of that website and after that it shows me this follow suggestion as I haven't follow it
On other hand I did same with already followed account it doesnt show all this. So I think it only shows if you never came across to that twitter handler or never followed it.